# Regex matching with Java Matcher won't find as expected

Tags: java, regex

Here is [the regex](http://regexr.com/3a7nq) I'm having issues with: `^(?:(\S+?)(?:\s+|\s*$))`.
I'm trying to match the 3 occurrences of this pattern in the following `String`:
`-execution  thisIsTest1  thisIsTest2`. Here is the method grabbing the first `numberOfArgs` elements and returning a `List<String>` filled with matched items. The problem is : the size of the returned `List` is 1.... The loop always iterate once and then exit...

```
private final String arguments="-execution  thisIsTest1  thisIsTest2";
 /**
 * Split the first N arguments separated with one or more whitespaces.
 * @return the array of size numberOfArgs containing the matched elements.
 */
...
public List<String> fragmentFirstN(int numberOfArgs){
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("^(?:(\\S+?)(?:\\s+|\\s*$))",Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher matc = patt.matcher(arguments);
    ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
    logg.info(arguments);
    int i = 0;
    while(matc.find()&&i<numberOfArgs){
        args.add(matc.group(1));
        i++;
    }
    return args;
}
```

And here is the test class :

```
private String[] argArr={"-execution",
        "thisIsTest1",
        "thisIsTest2"
};
...
@Test
public void testFragmentFirstN() throws Exception {
    List<String> arr = test.fragmentFirstN(3);
    assertNotNull(arr);
    System.out.println(arr); ----> prints : [-execution]
    System.out.println(test.getArguments()); ----> prints : -execution  thisIsTest1  thisIsTest2 <-----
    assertEquals(argArr[0],arr.get(0));
--->assertEquals(argArr[1],arr.get(1));<---- IndexOutOfBoundException : Index: 1, Size: 1
    assertEquals(argArr[2],arr.get(2));
    assertEquals(3,arr.size());
}
```

I thought `Matcher#find()` would match all possible char sequence when looped over. What am I missing?

Comment: I think the answer is that `^` matches the beginning of the input string, which means that `find` will only find the first one--after you skip over it, you're no longer at the beginning of the input string.  I believe there's either a regex command or a `Matcher` method to move the anchoring point so that it matches the point where the previous `find` left off, but I'll need to check the docs since I don't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: Try using `\G` instead of `^` (i.e. `\\G` in the Java string literal).

Comment: @ajb : Here it is! How could I miss it... thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the regex has a boundary matcher that matches the *start* of the input string (the `^` character). The first time `Matcher.find()` is invoked in the loop, the matched substring is `-execution`. This is because `-execution` starts at the beginning of the string and the regex has the part `(?:\\s+|\\s*$)` that means detects either space characters (which is the case after `-execution`) or non-space characters at the end of the input string.

The second iteration will not match any string because the matcher is no longer at the start of the input string. Hence `Matcher.find()` returns false.

You can try removing the character:

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\S+?)(?:\\s+|\\s*$))",
            Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

**EDIT:**

Based on @ajb's comments, simply removing the `^` character would make the regex match an input string that starts with whitespace. In case this is not desired, you can instead replace `^` with `\G` which marks the end of the previous match by the matcher:

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\G(?:(\\S+?)(?:\\s+|\\s*$))",
            Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Comment: But that changes the behavior if the original string starts with whitespace, I think?  It might work if the program makes a separate check for strings beginning with whitespace.

Comment: @ajb If the string starts with whitespace, the matcher will skip this whitespace in the first iteration, no?

Comment: Actually starting with a whitespace is not intended, but is not critical for my prorgam. Thanks though!

Comment: I think the original regex would reject the string, since the regex effectively starts with `^` and `\S`.  Removing the `^` changes that behavior.

Comment: @ajb I see your point. I updated the answer in case whitespace at the input start is not accepted.